# Unable to send WebDriver instance between scenarios residing in different feature files(SpecFlow)

Tags: automation

Background: Automating Sitecore Content Editor.
Tools Used:SpecFlow,Selenium C#

Issue:Unable to send the Selenium WebDriver instance between SpecFlow Scenarios.

Eg:
Helper Class - Creates the instance of Webdriver for every scenario.
UtlilityClass - Utility Class inherits from Helper Class .Has Login Scenario which is used by other scenarios in different feature files.
Multicolumn Class - Contains scenario -  Runs Login functionality from Utility Class and does further steps .

******************CODE*******************************
****Helper Class has only WebDriver and creation of Browser instance ****

Helper Class
{
protected WebDriverHelper WebDriver { get; private set; }
[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario(){WebDriver = WebDriverHelper.Create("SiteCoreAdminPage");}

[AfterScenario]
 public void AfterScenario(){WebDriver.Dispose(); }
 }

---

**UtilityFeature-**

Scenario:Login Functionality
Given Login

**UtilityDefinitionFile**

Utility Class has all the common functions to be utilised across scenarios.
UtilityClass:Helper Class
{
public void Login()
{
/*Perform all activities to log in*/
}
}

---

**Multicolumn Feature File-**

Scenario:
Given Login
Then CreateMulticolumnPage

**Multicolumn Definition File-**

Multicolumn:HelperClass
{
public void CreateMulticolumnPage()
{
 /*When code reaches this point , another instance of Webdriver is created.I don't want the instance to be created but instead continue the actions in already existing instance of webdriver.
}
}
****************CODE ENDS********************

Answer (score 1):

SpecFlow will generate tests for each of your scenario.

```
[Test]
public void A()
{
     // runs Scenario A
}

[Test]
pubic void B()
{
    // runs Scenario B
}
```

Tests will be executed by test runner (VS Test Explorer, Resharper, TestDriven.NET, etc.). There is no strict order how this tests will be executed. Test B can be executed separately, can be executed sententiously with A. You can not guarantee that order will be always A=>B. That is why it is not good idea to continue running B after A.

What you can do: move common part test A and B to separate method:

```
IWebDriver WebDriver;

[Test]
public void A()
{
     CommonPart();
     // runs Scenario A
}

[Test]
pubic void B()
{
    CommonPart();
    // runs Scenario B
}

private void CommonPart()
{
    WebDriver = WebDriverHelper.Create("SiteCoreAdminPage");
    //login
}
```

Comment: I have added classes and how I have done the coding .Please review and let me know how I can pass the WebDriver instance from 1 scenario to other so that I don't get new instance created every scenario .

Comment: Smitha, on this site we actually prefer votes over "thank you" comments :-)